# Customize checkbox on/off using images

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to toggle checkbox using css, toggling using on/off images. But however it is not happening, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8WV9/).

```
<div class="checkbox">  
<input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" data-role="none">  
<label for="check1">I agree</label>  
</div>

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    background: transparent url('../img/Check_box_2.png.png') no-repeat center!  important; 
}
.checkbox label:before {
    background: transparent url('../img/Check_box.png.png') no-repeat center center !important; 
}
```

Comment: Whatch for the filename of the background images. You seem to have duplicate `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but I'm pretty sure this will help you get to the right path:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    background: transparent url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-32-32-9.jpg') no-repeat center! important;
    content: ".";
    width: 32px; height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.checkbox label:before {
    background: transparent url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-32-32-4.jpg') no-repeat center center !important;
    content: ".";
    width: 32px; height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/c8WV9/1/

Comment: It should behave as toggle image on/off, i mean the one you have displayed before checking is fine, and after the checkbox is checked, the old image should hide and bring in the new image.